# SPRING Cron expression is not working on FRIDAY

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, crontrigger

I have to create the batch job which will run based on the time zone.

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("0 55 23 ? * MON-FRI", TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Toronto"));
taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(() -> lunchJob(job), cronTrigger);
```

The above program is running on CET time zone
This is working as expected from Monday to Thursday, not executing on FRIDAY.

Is it some wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"America/Toronto" is not a valid (Java) time zone. For the Canada Eastern Standard Time use "America/Montreal".

Comment: Even if I use "America/Montreal", it is not executing on FRIDAY when application is running on CET time zone

Comment: Well, it works as expected. Friday 23:55 in Montreal is Saturday 05:55 in Central Europe. You should use the same time zone for the CRON configuration and for the application.